# MissingMethodException:Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, runtime, identity

I'm having problem running my ASP.NET CORE MVC app. The error is at runtime and what I get is

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1..ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1<System.__Canon>, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1<System.__Canon>, Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions>, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1<System.__Canon>>, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationSchemeProvider)'.

I read all about the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and the changes between the version and everything. I tried all versions of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity but I'm getting the same error at runtime and I don't know where is the problem. The Netcoreapp is version 3.1 and right now I'm trying to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity version 5.0.0. I've downgraded everything to 2.2.0 and still getting same error..

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.11.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager<TUser> : SignInManager<User>
       where TUser : User
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(
            ApplicationUserManager<User> userManager,
            IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
            IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> claimsFactory,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            ILogger<SignInManager<User>> logger,
            IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider)
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemeProvider)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Such an error as `Method not found` usually means that you are using a combination of packages of wrong versions.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the context. Can you provide more code, please? It would be great if we can reproduce it.

Comment: this link might help - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14388#issuecomment-534856268

Comment: Services.csproj
`<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
`

Comment: All versions are okay netcoreapp v3.1 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0". I'm thinking that maybe Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" must be 3.0 but there isn't a version 3.0.0...so what am i supposed to do

Answer (score 4):

I am still getting this error message using .net 6.0.  I found this github discussion that indicated a breaking change in the SignInManager implementation.

https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/14828

They have added a seventh parameter to the constructor.

My csproj file referenced

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0"/>
```

which is the latest version of this library.  However, it appears to include the old version of the SignInManager with only 6 constructor parameters.

the old version of the SignInManager Constructor looked like this.

```
public AppSignInManager(AppUserManager userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
    IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
    ILogger<AppSignInManager> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
{
    
}
```

I was able to rectify this issue by also referencing:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="6.0.3"/>
```

The new SignInManager constructor looks like this.

```
public AppSignInManager(AppUserManager userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
    IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
    ILogger<AppSignInManager> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes,
    IUserConfirmation<AppUser> confirmation) : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes,confirmation)
{
    
}
```

Comment: Had the same issue, although I fixed it with the Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI package.